# Why prom-client is not showing registered metrics in the metrics endpoint?

Tags: nestjs, metrics, prom-client

I have just registered some metrics in a NestJS application, through a typescript decorator. I use the `prom-client` package, but although I can log the metrics registered, the endpoint is not exposing those, and the Prometheus docker instance that I use to show all metrics, are not showing those neither.

how can I do to view registered metrics in /metrics endpoint and the Prometheus dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved passing to the custom metric in the constructor options the registry that will be used as follow:

```js
new Counter({ name, help, registers: [registerOn] })
```

where `registerOn` is a reference of the **register** instance (from `prom-client`) used in the main module (because the metrics registered in different modules are registered in different registry instances)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use global Registry you should import register instead Registry...

Like: `import { register } from 'prom-client'`